# Getting ID value from second level of Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm sure this is a very newbie question, but I'm stuck.

```
$apinstaller = get_sub_field_object("installer", "user_{$userid}");

print_r($apinstaller);
```

When I print this $apinstaller array I see this...

Array ( [ID] => 1297 [key] => field_5e9b6d60c718e [label] => Installer [name] => appointment_0_installer [prefix] => acf [type] => post_object [value] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 303 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2017-12-29 07:17:22 [post_date_gmt] => 2017-12-29 07:17:22 [post_content] =>

```
$installerid = $apinstaller['ID'];
```

So when I echo the $installerID I get '1297', when really I want to be getting '303', which you can see is within that array, but as part of the WP_Post Object.

How can I target that part of the array?

Comment: the ID you are talking about is in the `value` array. You first have to get the `value` key then `id` key, which is in fact an object field, so you have to use the object member notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see 303 like this

```
$installerid = $apinstaller['value']->ID;
```